# Round Rect Button in Settings

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, settings.bundle

I have an application in which contain "Clear Cache" functionality.

How can I implement a Round Rect button or similar kind of functionality in Settings bundle?  This functionality exists in "Safari's Settings".

Any suggestion or code about this will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add buttons to your Settings.bundle preferences. The SDK doesn't support this. (Safari can do it, of course, because Apple can do whatever they want with their apps.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add buttons to your Settings.bundle preferences.

I suggest either making a "Switch" in the settings panel that triggers a "Clear Cache" on startup, or build a settings panel inside of your app.